# how to create date from data format year month day1 day2 day3 day4 .........day31

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

My data file (daily rainfall data) has the format

```
df = Year  Month   Day01  Day02  Day03 ..............Day31 
      1970   1       0        0    20                  3.5
      1970   2       0        0    20                  3.5
      1970   3       0        0    20                  3.5
      ...    .       .        .    ..                  ...
      ...    .       .        .    ..                  ...
```

and I want to read the above data into date format

```
df = date (year-month-day)
```

Please help
you can find the data here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sPRiRDYmWyTuuhks3CDWXj0eNcddsJopUNfjEAlSI-w/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you already have a dataframe with the following format:

```
YEAR  MN  DRF01  DRF02  DRF03  DRF04  DRF05  DRF06  DRF07  DRF08  DRF09  DRF10  DRF11  DRF12  DRF13  DRF14  DRF15  DRF16  DRF17  DRF18  DRF19  DRF20  DRF21  DRF22  DRF23  DRF24  DRF25  DRF26  DRF27  DRF28  DRF29  DRF30  DRF31
1971   1    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   22.0    0.0    0.0    4.6
1971   2    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    NaN    NaN    NaN
1971   3    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
1971   4    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   25.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    8.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    2.0    0.0    0.0    8.6    0.0    0.0    0.0    7.4   24.0    0.0    NaN
1971   5    3.6    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    1.0    0.0   40.0    0.0    0.0  106.0    0.0    2.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    3.0    6.6    0.0    0.0   22.6   26.8   12.8
```

You can get what you want by stacking the columns. The ideal dataframe for stacking should only contain the columns you want to stack, with the remaining columns moved to the index:

```
result = df.rename(columns={'MN': 'MONTH'}) \
           .set_index(['YEAR', 'MONTH']) \
           .rename_axis('DAY', axis=1) \
           .stack() \
           .to_frame('RAINFALL') \
           .reset_index()
result['DAY'] = result['DAY'].str[-2:].astype('int')
result['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(result[['YEAR', 'MONTH', 'DAY']])
```

Result:

```
YEAR  MONTH  DAY  RAINFALL       DATE
1971      1    1       0.0 1971-01-01
1971      1    2       0.0 1971-01-02
1971      1    3       0.0 1971-01-03
1971      1    4       0.0 1971-01-04
1971      1    5       0.0 1971-01-05
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `df.melt` might be even more straight forward :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': {0: 1910, 1: 1910, 2: 1911},
                   'Month': {0:1, 1:1, 2:2},
                   'Day 1': {0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 5},
                   'Day 2': {0: 2, 1: 4, 2: 6}})

print(df)
day_columns = [i for i in df.columns if 'Day' in i]
df = pd.melt(df,id_vars=['Year','Month'],value_vars=day_columns,var_name='Day',value_name='Rain')
df['Day'] = df['Day'].str.replace('Day ','')
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['Year', 'Month', 'Day']])
print(df)
```